# If $x \in A$ , then $x \notin \mathcal{P}(A)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

If $x$ exist in set $A$ , then $x$ doesn't exist in $\mathcal{P}(A)$ right? (Because *power set* of a set $A$ includes all the sets that are subsets of $A$)

By definition, if $X \in \mathcal{P}(A)$, then $X$ is a subset of $A$.

Answer (score 9):

Let $A=\{\{\}\}$ and $X=\{\}$.

Comment: By X I meant an object in A not another group.           A={x}, x∈A , but x /∈  in P(A).

Comment: @jonhkonstantin note that if $X \in \mathcal{P}(A)$, then $X$ is a subset of $A$, not an element of $A$. The notions of *subset* and *element* are different

Comment: @jonhkonstantin I do not understand your comment.  Hagen gave an example of an $X$ which happens to simultaneously be an element and a subset of another set $A$.  Do not make the mistake in thinking that sets may not themselves be elements of other sets and do not make the mistake in thinking that all elements of a set have the same "depth"

Comment: Yes, it so happens that many times (*but not necessarily all times*) you will have examples of elements of a set which are not also subsets of the set, or have examples of subsets of a set which are not also elements of a set... but it is possible, as shown here, that you might have elements *which are also subsets* of a set.

Comment: @johnkonstantin Check this out: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers . Basically, one model of natural numbers in set theory is: $0=\emptyset, 1=\{0\}, 2=\{0,1\},3=\{0,1,2\}$ etc. In this construction, $0\in 1\in 2\in\ldots$ and also $0\subseteq 1\subseteq 2\subseteq\ldots$.

Comment: I take it this is the counterexample? @StinkingBishop

Comment: @MyMathYourMath I would not say this is *the* counterexample. Hagen von Eitzen's example is a good counterexample. Mine is another counterexample (which I thought would be nice to know). (Also, with my counterexample I wanted to preempt the OP's potential additional questions, like "ok, it seems trivial if $X$ is allowed to be an empty set, but can $X$ be a nonempty set?)

Answer (score 1):

It even can happen for every element of $A$; *i,e;* $\forall x\in A(x\subset A)$. This kind of sets are called [*Transitive*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_set). Examples of this sets are each ordinal number.